# Functionally retrieving rows from a database in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Consider the following piece of code:

```
var result = List[Measurement]()

val dbResult = conn.createStatement.executeQuery(unsentMeasurements)

while(dbResult.next) {
  result ::= Measurement(dbResult.getString("stuff"), dbResult.getString("morestuff"))
}

result.reverse
```

Versus this:

```
val dbResult = conn.createStatement.executeQuery(unsentMeasurements)

Stream.continually(dbResult).takeWhile(_.next) map { r =>
  Measurement(r.getString("stuff"), r.getString("morestuff"))
}
```

Any flaws in my rationale? Any improvements?

Comment: The second example looks better to me. I can't try it out right now, but is there a possibility to use `Iterator` instead of `Stream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is not purely functional, although it represents an improvement. What would a purely functional solution look like?

```
trait Sql[A] { self =>
  def unsafePerformIO(ds: javax.sql.DataSource): A = unsafePerformIO(ds.createConnection)

  def unsafePerformIO(conn: java.sql.Connection): A //abstract

  def map(f: A => B): Sql[B] = new Sql[B] { 
    def unsafePerformIO(conn: Connection) = f(self.unsafePerformIO(conn))
  }
  def flatMap(f: A => Sql[B]): Sql[B] = new Sql[B] { 
    def unsafePerformIO(conn: Connection)
      = f(self.unsafePerformIO(conn)).unsafePerformIO(conn)
  }

}
```

I imagine you might say "huh?" at this point. Let me introduce the companion:

```
object Sql {
  def apply[A](comp: Connection => A) = new Sql[A] {
    def unsafePerformIO(conn: Connection) = comp(conn)
  }
}
```

The idea (of course) is that you delay side-effects until the end of the world, encapsulating the values returned by the database in a type that represents *value returned from DB call*, in the same way `Option` represents *value which may not exist*.

The usage becomes something like this:

```
Sql { conn => process( conn.prepareStatement.executeQuery ) }
```

Where the `process` method might look like your code (above) perhaps.

I imagine this may raise a few questions:

### What the? Huh? I mean, what the?

Well, it allows you to do something like this:

```
def getStuff1: Sql[Int]
def getStuff2: Sql[Int]
def useStuff(i: Int): Sql[String]
```

Then you can compose using for-comprehensions

```
val result = 
  for {
    i <- getStuff1
    j <- getStuff2
    s <- useStuff(i + j)
  } 
  yield s
```

What is the type of this expression? Well, it's an `Sql[String]` of course! To get hold of the String:

```
result.unsafePerformIO(myDataSource)
```

This creates a single connection which is then threaded through the computation.

What is missing? Well, resource management (i.e. cleaning up the connections of course). I understand this will all be available in **scalaz7**

Comment: So you ah.. hmm.. made an Sql Monad? :)